# What is the name of the flower in the photo?

Tags: bonsai

I have bought a Juniperus bonsai before few weeks. Now this flower has appeared, but it does not look much like the one I have ordered. Please, tell me what is that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a common weed here in the US in the mustard family, often found in nursery pots and in waste places. It is not a US native. If I'm right, it would have small four-petalled white flowers. If you rip one of the newer leaves in half it should have a spicy smell if it's a mustard.